# Inverse of trigonometric functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I understand the intuition behind the inverses of trigonometric functions. 
But on the other hand formally there's no way that the trigonometric functions have an inverse because they are neither surjective or injective. How is this formally explained? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their domain and range is defined in such a way that the functions become injective and surjective.

In the case of $$f(x)=\sin^{-1}(x)$$
$$D_f=[-1,1] \space\space\space\space,\space\space\space\space R_f=\left[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$

The definitions of the other functions are similar (not exactly same though).

Refer [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Basic_properties) for additional information.

Comment: Do you mean $\arcsin(1)$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, my previous comment was really stupid and nonsensical. I'll delete it.

Comment: You are correct, in a way. $\sin(\frac{5\pi}{2})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$. It is only due to popular convention and better properties that the range of $\arcsin$ is defined to be $\left[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Comment: If you go to the link I referenced, you'll notice they say "Range of _usual_ principal value".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to restrict the domain and the range. For instance $\sin$ is a bijection from $[-\pi,\pi]\rightarrow [-1,-1]$ and therefore has an inverse that is a bijection from $[-1,1]\rightarrow [-\pi,\pi]$.

Another example is $\tan$. bijective from $]-\pi/2,\pi/2[\rightarrow ]-\infty,\infty[$ and has a bijective inverse $]-\infty,\infty[\rightarrow ]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$

Answer (score 0):

$\sin$ is one-to-one on $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, and $\cos$ is on $(0, \pi)$ for example.

So basically, that's how you build these functions : you use the restriction.

However, for example, if you ask for $\cos^{-1}(0)$ you will get $\frac{\pi}{2}$ while it could also be $\frac{5\pi}{2}$ for example.